# Did Philip Larkin use a swearword while quoting from Pym's Excellent Women?

Tags: quote-source, wording-choice, philip-larkin, barbara-pym, excellent-women

In a letter to Barbara Pym dated 18 July 1971, Philip Larkin allegedly wrote:

> I reread *Excellent Women* before coming away—what a marvellous set of characters it contains! Sometimes it's hard to believe they're all in the same book, Rocky, Helena, Dora & her milk jug tidies ... Perhaps, too, you'll tell me they *aren't* in the same book, but I think they are. *I* never see any Rockys, but almost every young academic wife ("**I'm a shit**") has something of Helena.
>
> <sub>Larkin, Philip. [*Selected Letters of Philip Larkin, 1940–1985*](https://archive.org/details/selectedletterso00lark/mode/2up). Ed. Anthony Thwaite. 1992. First American edition, New York: Farrar, Straus, 1993. [p. 442](https://archive.org/details/selectedletterso00lark/page/442/mode/2up). Accessed on archive.org 28 January 2024. Emphasis added.</sub>

The [Wikipedia entry for *Excellent Women*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_Women) quotes this letter.

The phrase "I'm a shit" does not occur anywhere in *Excellent Women*. It is hard to imagine the titular nice ladies of that novel using profanity. It's also hard to associate that phrase with Pym generally. Larkin's language is [a different matter entirely](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/48419/this-be-the-verse), but in context, the phrase appears to be meant as a quotation from Pym's novel. Is Larkin misremembering a phrase from the novel? Is he attributing poor self-esteem to Helena? Is he passing judgment on her? Is this a private joke between the two writers? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 25):

<sub>**Edited** to add screenshots of parts of the letter in question at the end of this answer.</sub>

The most likely answer is (e), something else entirely. The heading to this letter says that it was transcribed from manuscript (MS) rather than typescript (TS). The transcriber has probably misread the word.

In *Excellent Women*, the narrator, Mildred, recounts her first encounter with her new neighbor, Helena:

> "You'd hate sharing a kitchen with me. I'm such a slut," she said, almost proudly.

and a little further on:

> I hope you don't mind tea in mugs," she said, coming in with a try [sic]. "I told you I was a slut."
>
> <sub>Pym, Barbara. *Excellent Women* Ch. 1. 1958. Introduction by A. N. Wilson. New York: Penguin, 2006. p. 4.</sub>

Helena means *slut* in the first sense given in the OED:

> I.1. *depreciative*. An untidy, dirty, or slovenly woman; a woman who is habitually careless, lazy, or negligent with regard to appearance, household cleanliness, etc.; a slattern. Also rarely applied to a man. Now somewhat *dated*.
>
> <sub>“Slut, *N*., Sense I.1.” *Oxford English Dictionary*, Oxford UP, September 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/3665174539. Accessed 28 January 2024.</sub>

She does not mean it in the sense more common today:

> I.2.a. Chiefly *derogatory* and *offensive*. A sexually promiscuous or lascivious woman; (also) a female prostitute. In earlier use also: a vulgar, impudent, or disreputable woman. In recent use also occasionally applied to a man.
>
> <sub>“Slut, *N*., Sense I.2.a.” *Oxford English Dictionary*, Oxford UP, September 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1116694172. Accessed 28 January 2024.</sub>

The rest of the novel provides plentiful confirmation of Helena's being a slut in the now outdated sense of slatternly. On one occasion, Mildred smells something burning in Helena's kitchen and goes in to check:

> I found one of the gas rings full on and on it a saucepan of potatoes which had boiled dry and were now sticking to the bottom in a brownish mass. I dealt with them quickly but the saucepan was in a very bad state. I ran some water into it so that it could soak. I noticed with distaste and disapproval that the breakfast things and what appeared to be dishes and glasses from an even earlier date were not washed up. The table by the window was also crowded; there were two bottles of milk, each half-full, an empty gin bottle, a dish of butter melting in the sun, and a plate full of cigarette stubs.
>
> <sub>Pym, *ibid.*, Ch. 17. p. 136.</sub>

It's easy to imagine how the word *slut*, in cursive handwriting, could be misread for *shit*. I believe that whoever typed out the letter from Larkin's manuscript for Thwaite's collection made this mistake, and that Thwaite failed to notice it.

I cannot find an image of the manuscript of this letter online, but available samples of Larkin's handwriting do make this explanation plausible. For example, here is a page from a letter to his longtime girlfriend Monica Jones:

[image: Image of letter from Larkin to Monica Jones]

<sub>Retrieved from *Layabout*, [kekasden.blogspot.com](https://kekasden.blogspot.com/2010/10/philip-larkins-letters-to-monica-jones.html), 28 January 2024</sub>

The repeated word *sure* and the word *should* in this reproduction of Larkin's holograph shows that his cursive could theoretically be misread as **sme* / **smi* or **sliorild* respectively. Those aren't real words, so the context is sufficient to ensure that the word is read as intended. Further, the word *shit* does occur frequently in Larkin's letters to his other correspondents, appearing 42 times in the archive.org search results within Thwaite's collection. *Slut*, by contrast, appears nowhere therein. So for *slut* to be misread as *shit* would not be surprising. It is a safe hypothesis that this is what happened here.

**Edit 20240305.** Following @shoover's suggestion in the comments, I acquired a facsimile of the letter in question from the Pym archives at the Bodleian. The word is indeed mistranscribed. Here is a screenshot of the passage in question:

[image: Screenshot of portion of the manuscript of a letter from Philip Larkin to Barbara Pym]

> are. *I* never see any Rockys, but almost every young academic wife ("I'm a slut") has something of Helena.
>
> <sub>Larkin, Philip. Portion of letter to Barbara Pym, 18 July 1971. From the Barbara Pym archives, Bodleian Libary, Oxford. MS. Pym 151, fol. 74r.</sub>

It is easy to see how *slut* could be misread as *shit*. The similarity is notable when in the same letter, Larkin writes:

[image: Screenshot of different portion of letter from Larkin to Pym.]

> passing my driving test — **things** such as these? Life doesn't work that way.
>
> <sub>*ibid.*, fol. 73v</sub>

The *hi* of *things* looks very like the *lu* of *slut*. But we can confirm it's intended as *slut* and not *shit* by looking at the following fragment from the same letter:

[image: Screenshot of yet another portion of the Larkin-Pym letter]

> blessings of my advancing age is a merciful **blurring** of the sounds
>
> <sub>*ibid.*, fol. 73r</sub>

The similarity of the *lu* of *blurring* to the corresponding letters in the prior examples provides the needed confirmation that *lu* and *hi* are easily misidentified in Larkin's handwriting. The hypothesis can be regarded as confirmed: Larkin is indeed paraphrasing Helena's words, and the letter reads *I'm a **slut*** rather than *I'm a shit*.

Comment: If the letters are still extant, they are probably in the Barbara Pym archives at the Bodleian, specifically in the file [_Letters from Philip Larkin, 1961-1976_](https://archives.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/repositories/2/archival_objects/72033), since they do not appear to be in Larkin's archives at the same institution. You would need the help of a librarian/archivist to access (a digitization of) the letter itself.

Comment: @shoover Thanks for the info. Wanna start a GoFundMe to pay my way to Oxford?, he asked hopefully.

Comment: Haha... You could try writing to them.

Comment: @shoover Done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Good job tracking down the letter! One quibble, the ISO date 20240502 doesn't seem to have occurred yet.

Comment: @shoover oops. Fixed.